# Displaying Visio diagrams and pdf in Internet Explorer

Tags: html, asp.net, pdf, sharepoint, visio

I'm trying to display both Visio-diagrams (vsdx) and pdf-documents in a web part in SharePoint 2013 Foundation. I use Visio Viewer to display the diagrams in an HTML object and the pdf in another object. The user choose a file from a list and it displays the document, all in the same web part. There's no problem when choosing a Visio diagram or a pdf the first time but when chosing a pdf and switching back to a Visio-diagram the diagram becomes all messed up, like a web page that has lost it's CSS, and stays that way until i close all Explorer-windows and start it up again. There's no problems when switching back and forth between Visio-diagrams, only when the user have selected a pdf-document and then a Visio-diagram. It's very odd, could it have something to do with Adobe Reader I'm using to display the pdf?

I would appreciate any help I can get. If I can't get it to work it's not a big deal since it doesn't have to display the pdf but it sure would be nice.

Here's the code I use in the ascx-file:

```
<object classid="clsid:279D6C9A-652E-4833-BEFC-312CA8887857" style="border-left: solid 1px lightgray" width="1188" height="786" >
    <param name="BackColor" value="FFFFFFFF">
    <param name="AlertsEnabled" value="0">
    <param name="ContextMenuEnabled" value="1">
    <param name="GridVisible" value="1">
    <param name="HighQualityRender" value="1">
    <param name="PageColor" value="16777215">
    <param name="PageVisible" value="1">
    <param name="PropertyDialogEnabled" value="1">
    <param name="ScrollbarsVisible" value="0">
    <param name="ToolbarVisible" value="1">
    <param name="SRC" value="<%:selectedVisio %>">
    <param name="CurrentPageIndex" value="1">
    <param name="Zoom" value="-1">
</object>
<object src="<%:selectedPdf %>" style="border-left: solid 1px lightgray" width="1188" height="786"  />
```

Comment: Maybe you can re-create the html code (via javascript) each time you click on document ?

Comment: I tried it now but I can't get it to work. It was a good idea though, Max. Thanks.